# Select a file or a folder in QFileDialog pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

My scrip ist currently using QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames() to let the user select files within Windows explorer. Now I´m wondering if there is a way to let them select also folders, not just files. There are some similar posts, but none of them provides a working solution. I really dont want to use the QFileDialog file explorer to get around this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QFileDialog doesn't allow that natively. The only solution is to create your own instance, do some small "patching".

Note that in order to achieve this, you cannot use the *native* dialogs of your OS, as Qt has almost *no* control over them; that's the reason of the `dialog.DontUseNativeDialog` flag, which is mandatory.

The following code works as much as static methods do, and returns the selected items (or none, if the dialog is cancelled).

```
def getOpenFilesAndDirs(parent=None, caption='', directory='', 
                        filter='', initialFilter='', options=None):
    def updateText():
        # update the contents of the line edit widget with the selected files
        selected = []
        for index in view.selectionModel().selectedRows():
            selected.append('"{}"'.format(index.data()))
        lineEdit.setText(' '.join(selected))

    dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(parent, windowTitle=caption)
    dialog.setFileMode(dialog.ExistingFiles)
    if options:
        dialog.setOptions(options)
    dialog.setOption(dialog.DontUseNativeDialog, True)
    if directory:
        dialog.setDirectory(directory)
    if filter:
        dialog.setNameFilter(filter)
        if initialFilter:
            dialog.selectNameFilter(initialFilter)

    # by default, if a directory is opened in file listing mode, 
    # QFileDialog.accept() shows the contents of that directory, but we 
    # need to be able to "open" directories as we can do with files, so we 
    # just override accept() with the default QDialog implementation which 
    # will just return exec_()
    dialog.accept = lambda: QtWidgets.QDialog.accept(dialog)

    # there are many item views in a non-native dialog, but the ones displaying 
    # the actual contents are created inside a QStackedWidget; they are a 
    # QTreeView and a QListView, and the tree is only used when the 
    # viewMode is set to QFileDialog.Details, which is not this case
    stackedWidget = dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QStackedWidget)
    view = stackedWidget.findChild(QtWidgets.QListView)
    view.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(updateText)

    lineEdit = dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit)
    # clear the line edit contents whenever the current directory changes
    dialog.directoryEntered.connect(lambda: lineEdit.setText(''))

    dialog.exec_()
    return dialog.selectedFiles()
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much for that detailed answer, it works perfectly, i´ll guess i have to accept that i cant use the native OS dialog.

Comment: Just one more question, currently the QFiledialog has only a combobox on top where i can browse to several standard locations or insert the path to the selected file/folder directly. For my purposes i often have to navigate into really deep folder structures to select files or folder. Is there a way to go to a directory and see its files and folders by pasting in its path like on windows explorer?

Comment: Be aware: if user types (any) character into the edit widget and then presses **Backspace**, you get an "infinite recursion" from the `lineEdit.setText(' '.join(selected))` line.  Tested under Ubuntu 22.04 with Qt 5.15 from the distribution.  Discussion and workaround at https://forum.qt.io/topic/152074/getting-recursionerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-while-calling-a-python-object/2

Comment: @JonBrave Thanks for that, I clearly underestimated that aspect. I'll check into it as soon as I'll have enough time to test it as required. Based on the description, the signal block may work around the issue (I'd use a QSignalBlocker, though), but I'm not completely sure it actually solves the real problem behind it, as it may be just a symptom of an underlying aspect that could have other consequences too. I will do some further research on the matter as soon as possible, including inspecting the Qt sources, and verifying possible changes between versions.